# SVG text baseline position in Chrome not scale-invariant

Tags: svg, text, viewbox, baseline

I have an SVG containing the words "foo" and "bar":

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <text x="10px" y="10px" font-size="10px">
        foo
    </text>
    <text x="10px" y="10px" font-size="10px" dominant-baseline="hanging">
        bar
    </text>
</svg>
```

And another SVG that is nearly identical, except the coordinate system is scaled down by a factor of 10:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
    <text x="1px" y="1px" font-size="1px">
        foo
    </text>
    <text x="1px" y="1px" font-size="1px" dominant-baseline="hanging">
        bar
    </text>
</svg>
```

In Safari and Firefox, these two SVGs produce approximately the same results on screen, but in Chrome the latter SVG has a large gap between the two lines of text.

Is this a bug? And is there a way to display my text that is compatible with all three browsers while still allowing me to use the viewBox settings I want?

Comment: I'm sorry I won't help determine if it is a bug or not, but isn't your page zoom level below 100% on chrome ? That's the only way for me to reproduce on both chrome 58 and 60.

Comment: Browsers are optimised for the kind of font sizes that generally occur in content. They all have bugs that have been around for years with content outside that usual range.

Comment: @Kaiido: I'm using Chrome version 58.0.3029.96 (64-bit) on Mac OS 10.11.6 and I'm at 100% zoom.